# Mongoose Schema created using CommonJS not working again after porting to Module

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I started out my Mongoose Schema declarations using CommonJS as shown below and populate was working perfectly.

For CommonJS I have:

**author.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const AuthorSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    first_name: String,
    last_name: String,
    email: String,
}, {
    timestamps: {
        createdAt: 'created_at',
        updatedAt: 'updated_at'
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Author', AuthorSchema);
```

**comment.js**

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const CommentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    text: String,
    author: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Author'
    }
}, {
    timestamps: {
        createdAt: 'created_at',
        updatedAt: 'updated_at'
    }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Comment', CommentSchema);
```

and the below query worked flawlessly when using CommonJS

```
let comments = await Comment.find({ author: authorId })
        .populate("author", 'first_name last_name _id').limit(10);
```

Now, my team wanted us to move away from CommonJS to modules and so I added `type:module` to my `package.json` file and attempted to refactor the schema declarations above to the following:

**new_author.js**

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const AuthorSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    first_name: String,
    last_name: String,
    email: String,
}, {
    timestamps: {
        createdAt: 'created_at',
        updatedAt: 'updated_at'
    }
});

export default mongoose.model('Author', AuthorSchema);
```

and

**new_comment.js**

```
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const CommentSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    _id: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    text: String,
    author: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'Author'
    }
}, {
    timestamps: {
        createdAt: 'created_at',
        updatedAt: 'updated_at'
    }
});

export default mongoose.model('Comment', CommentSchema);
```

and all of a sudden the following query no longer works

```
let comments = await Comment.find({ author: authorId })
            .populate("author", 'first_name last_name _id').limit(10);
```

The error I keep getting back is

```
MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "Author".
```

This is unbelievable. As you can see above, nothing changed other than using `imports` and `export default` statements.

Answer (score 0):

I think there might be problem with your table names.Try to change table names
when you changed your schema files.

```
mongoose.model('newModelName', modelSchema);
```

Comment: I didn't change the table names. They are the same. I only changed ```module.exports``` to ```export default``` that's all

Comment: I suggested you to change your table names once.